# Connect-flash message is not working for res.render("SomeView")

Tags: node.js, express, npm, connect-flash

I am not able to use connect-flash package for res.render.
My main aim is to display a flash message on rendering of a view.

I am able to make it work with a res.redirect("route") but not with the res.render("view") code. Is it by design ?

My code is shown as below

```
if(err){
      // Apparently res.render("register") didn't work with flash. But res.redirect("/register") worked.
        req.flash("error", err.message);   // Error occurs when the user is taken, password is empty etc.
        return res.redirect("/register");  // Short circut everything. Else the code below this would run as well and that would throw an error
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the correct syntax for using req.flash with res.render:

```
req.flash('error', yourErrString);
res.render("register.ejs", {
   message: req.flash('error')
});
```

Comment: I was trying to do something similar to this.

`app.get("/",function(req,res){
    req.flash("error", err.message); 
    res.render("index", { message : req.flash('error') });
}`

Guess this is not the way connect-flash is supposed to work

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me; In my case, I was okay to refresh the page once again it loaded;

```
window.onload = function () {
    if (!window.location.hash) {
        window.location = window.location + '#loaded';
        window.location.reload();
    }
}
```

Comment: if you are using ejs then link a script tag at the start of the page so that it reloads and flash message appears.